# Best practice to handle third party SSL certificate in Java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I'm working on an application that calls a third-party webservice over https. So I need to add this certificate to the truststore of my application. I can see 3 solutions to fix my problem:

- add this certificate to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`
- create a custom truststore and launch my JVM with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= ...`
- programatically load this truststore when starting my application

Which solution do you recommend/discourage me to use?

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer the second one. Because;

For the first one; when you change your java version you need to do extra work (you must add these ssl certs to cacerts again).

For the third one; when you need to add another ssl cert. you must change your code.

So, the second is the best choice because;  you will not need to change your code when new ssl comes (You will just add it to external trustStore) and you will do nothing for these certs when you upgrade your java version.

Comment: "when you need to add another ssl cert. you must change your code" this is not correct, you can set the keystore via properties file or another mechanism. "the second is the best choice", neither is correct, depends on the complexity of your app and on the application type, standalone, webapp... etc, maybe you need the use of multiple credential stores to maintaining a separate SSL context per individual target interaction encapsulating each context in a new SSLContext object.